# Prestashop 1.6 Database inserting products

Tags: sql, prestashop-1.6

I've added product by sql query but even when I have ps_product_shop and ps_product_lang set correctly the product in back office is shown with null name and no description what so ever and additionaly there is no category connection too.

What am I missing, can I add product by SQL? If so how do I do it.

I was looking everywhere but there was no query to help me, if someone could help me out I would appreciate that.

Comment: please show me the sql query

Comment: I didn't use query just yet. Just using insert function in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Manually adding products directly to database through sql query is not advisable. If you did so, problem may be your `id_lang` field in `ps_product_lang` table. For English id_lang is `1`. Please check with your query.

Here I did for English lang. You can add through code like below otherwise you can use admin panel for product creation.

```
$product = new Product();
$product->name[1] = "This is test product";
$product->description[1] = "Description";
$product->description_short[1] = "Descriptio short";
$product->active = 1;
$product->condition = "new";
$product->link_rewrite = Tools::link_rewrite('This is test product');;
$product->id_tax_rules_group = 1;
$product->price = 100;
$product->wholesale_price = 90;
$product->id_manufacturer = 1;
$product->add();
```

Comment: Thanks, but adding product through PHP is not what I need. I need to add it manually by SQL Query. And no I didn't forget id_lang field, I set it to 1 as all products added by Prestashop use it.

Comment: @Aksebkit - So you need SQL queries to insert product data. Correct?

Comment: I've managed to set products by sql query but still there is problem with them not being in any category but they should be in default one I set in ps_product, right?